# Update value in firebase firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

[image: this is the image of firestore document]

I want to update dislikes, likes, fav individually when the user clicks on the like, dislike, or favorite button, but when I try to update the whole feelings map is updating.

```
  if (course.feelings.fav.contains(currentUser.email)) {
    course.feelings.fav.remove(currentUser.email)
    db.runBatch { batch ->
        batch.update(noteRef, "feelings",FieldValue.arrayRemove(currentUser))
        batch.update(favNoteRef, "feelings", FieldValue.arrayRemove(currentUser))
    }
} else {
    course.feelings.fav.add(currentUser.email.toString())
}

db.runBatch { batch ->
    batch.update(noteRef, "feelings",course.feelings.fav)
    batch.update(favNoteRef, "feelings", course.feelings.fav)
}
```

This is the code which is called when the user clicks on the fav button

Comment: I don't have any errors, I am trying to update the value of like, dislike, and fav but this is not working

Comment: @HiteshPatel Are you still facing this error?

Answer (score 1):

You can update nested fields of a document by using the dot notation.
If you want to update the `fav` field inside `feelings`, you can use:

```kotlin
batch.update(noteRef, "feelings.fav",course.feelings.fav)
```

Refer [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects) for detailed info.

Comment: Yes, i was facing the issue, so i change the database to solve the problem